# Need an excel formula/trick to convert a column of hyperlink to substring of hyperlink

Tags: excel, office365

I have a list of jira links having a format of “https://jira.com/browse/**ADCS-262**” where the bold part gets changed.

Is there a way to convert all these links to **ADCS-262** format perserving the links

Comment: Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HYPERLINK function into spreadsheet.

Sample

```
=HYPERLINK("https://jira.com/browse/ADCS-262","ADCS-262")
```

Next actions:
get last part of link

=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","#",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","")))))

and combine both functions

```
a2 = https://jira.com/browse/ADCS-262
f2 = =RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","#",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","")))))
g2 = =HYPERLINK(A2,F2)
```

[image]

Happy coding!